# On iOS systems, take photos with h5 will cause the browser to flash back

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have searched Baidu and Google for a long time, but still haven't gained anything。

The specific situation is as follows:
https://cdn.vipxufan.com/questions/20230322-134527.mp4

On iOS systems, usingto take photos with h5 will cause the browser to flash back。

html code

```
<img src="xxx" onclick="startPhoto"/>
```

javascript code

```
startPhoto(){
    document.getElementById( 'inputElementId').click()

}
//I will call this method after the page is loaded
createInputFile(){
    let input = document.createElement("input")
    input.id = 'inputElementId'
    input.type = 'file'
    input.accept = 'image/*'
    input.capture = 'camera'
    input.onchange = this.photo
    input.style.width = '10px'
    input.style.height = '10px'
    input.style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('box').append(input);
},

photo( e){
    const files = e.target.files;
    let file = files[0];
    
    if( !window.FileReader) {
        return '对不起，您的设备不支持上传图片'
    }
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let key = this.choseKey
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        let data = e.target.result;
        
        if(key == 'panorama'){
            this.uploadedImgsPanorama.push( data)
        }else if(key == 'ornaments' ){
            this.uploadedImgsOrnaments.push( data)
        }else if(key == 'equipment' ){
            this.uploadedImgsEquipment.push( data)
        }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

The requirement is that pictures cannot be uploaded, and only users are allowed to take photos to upload

My English is very poor, and I used translation software to ask questions. If I disturb you, I am so sorry.

Comment: Hint: `HTMLInputElement.files`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code, you can use Safari's developer tools to look at it, and you can see the error message in the console.

It may be a permission issue, or a **`Content-Security-Policy`** issue.